# How to customize the landing page information within Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am trying to implement Stack Overflow for Teams where I work, and I have just realized that a user who is not allowed to access the Team does not have any contact information (first phase is invite-based only, and the second will include domains to allow to easily join):

[image: Not a Stack Overflow for Teams member yet landing page]

Of course, the announcement for joining the team can include this information, but ideally this should also be available within this landing page.

How do I customize the landing page information within Stack Overflow for Teams to include some contact information?

---

This has been partially mitigated by adding minimal contact information on the landing page (which I think is a great compromise between not exposing too much data vs. not being informative at all):

[image: New landing page]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not allow the ability to customize this landing page.

Since this page is publicly facing (someone can discover the URL), we wouldn't want to expose the email of the admin for security purposes.

Comment: This seems to have changed recently. While the landing page cannot be customized, if I try to access a team I am no longer part of I receive a landing page saying something like: `Have a question? Contact {the display name of an admin}`.

Comment: @Alexei I just checked in my Team where I'm an admin but I can't find an option where I should be able to change this. Maybe that option comes with the business-tier.

Comment: @rene AFAIK, you cannot change this. Stack seems to add there some display name of an admin (probably the "oldest" one).